# QT and the new signal slot syntax, slot for QApplication::quit outside main function

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to test the old and new QT slot/signal syntax. The old style works ok, the new only works in main function, it does not work if we pass the app object to another function. The VS 2017 compiler generates error C2665: "A parameter of the overloaded function cannot be converted to the required type".

```
void testTimer(const QApplication& app)
{
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &app, SLOT(quit())); // OK - works
    // This generates compiler error C2665:
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &app, &QApplication::quit); // Compiler error
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &app, SLOT(quit())); // OK - works
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &app, &QApplication::quit); // OK - works

    testTimer(app);

    app.exec();
}
```

Comment: You need to try exactly the same code that is in `main()`, in a function that isn't called `main()`.

Comment: Change to `void testTimer(QApplication *app){QTimer::singleShot(1000, app, &QApplication::quit); }` and `testTimer(&app);`

Comment: My code is exactly the same in the main and in the testTimer function. I also try to use a pointer to app but it gives the same result.

Comment: @Klearuegh a wild guess - remove `const` from `QApplication& app` function `testTimer` parameter? note: `quit` is a static slot, not really sure why an object would be relevant here at all

Comment: Thank's a lot, after removing const there's no compiler errors. I spend 2 hours on that :)

Comment: @Klearuegh No, it is clearly not exactly the same. Just look at the code.

Comment: This doesn't work because `quit` is a static member. Try it with a properly typed non-static member and it'll work just fine with a const object pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Why? `QCoreApplication::quit` is a class method: it doesn't need an object at all. You should invoke it like a C function pointer:

```
QTimer::singleShot(1000, &QCoreApplication::quit);
```

And even if it did - you're supposed to use `qApp`. The application is effectively a global singleton whose lifetime you control. Passing it around is unnecessary.

If you try it on an actual non-static member, you'll see that it works just fine (tested with Qt 5.10). Qt even lets you shoot yourself in the leg:

```
#include <QTimer>
#include <utility>

struct Foo : QObject {
   void slot() const {}
   void nonConstSlot() {}
};

void test(const Foo *foo) {
   QTimer::singleShot(900, foo, &Foo::slot);
}

template <typename P, typename M, typename> struct valid {
   static std::false_type value;
};

template <typename P, typename M> struct valid<P, M, decltype((*P().*M())())> {
   static std::true_type value;
};

template <typename P, typename M, typename ...Args> constexpr bool isValid(P, M, Args...) {
   return valid<P, M, void>::value;
}

int main() {
   const Foo foo;
   QTimer::singleShot(1000, &foo, &Foo::slot);
   QTimer::singleShot(1000, &foo, &Foo::nonConstSlot); //oops
   static_assert(isValid(&foo, &Foo::slot), "");
   static_assert(!isValid(&foo, &Foo::nonConstSlot), ""); // (foo.*&Foo::nonConstSlot)() must be invalid
   test(&foo);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know where is the problem when I was testing new style syntax. It seems that you can't use constants in a new style unless you manually do type conversion. Lesson for future.

Comment: @Klearuegh That's false.